# Clojure Keyword and Optional Argument Problem

Tags: clojure, argument-passing, optional-parameters

I want to create a function that takes in a required argument x, and either a optional argument opt1 OR a keyword argument opt2.

Right now I have

```
(defn foo x & [opt1 {:keys [opt2]}]
  ...
```

But the above signature only lets me pass in keyword argument opt2 when both x and opt1 is present like

```
(foo 'x 'opt1 {:opt2 'opt2})
```

not like this

```
(foo 'x {:opt2 'opt2})
```

Please help me create a function that takes a required argument X and either opt1 or opt2, where opt2 is a keyword argument.

Thank you.

EDIT: I want to do the same for other macros as well. So I still need to use the defmacro.

Comment: Consider using `defnk` from [clojure.contrib.def](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/def-api.html) instead of explicit destructuring.

Comment: `defnk` is deprecated in favor of more consistent built-in functionality as of 1.2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is ambiguity.  Consider a function `(fn foo [x y & args])` that takes two optional arguments and then any number of keyword arguments.  If you then call it like `(foo :bar :baz)`, how does your program handle it?  `x` => `:bar`, `y` => `:baz`?  Or `x` and `y` not provided, with a single `:bar` => `:baz` keyword argument?

Even in Common Lisp, which has arguably even more flexibility than Clojure in parsing function parameters, mixing optional and keyword arguments is not recommended, according to at least [one popular book](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/functions.html).

Your best bet is to change all of your arguments to positional arguments, or all of your parameters to keyword arguments.  If you use keyword arguments, you can use hash-map destructuring to provide defaults for "optional" keyword parameters.

```
user> (defn foo [& {:keys [x y bar] 
                    :or {x 1 y 2 bar 3}}] 
        (prn [x y bar]))
#'user/foo
user> (foo)
[1 2 3]
nil
user> (foo :bar :baz)
[1 2 :baz]
nil
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to check if the aditional arguments are keyword arguments or not anyway (I assume your or is an exclusive or) so you can do it like this:

```
(defn foo [& args] 
    (if (= (count args) 1)
        (let [[opt1] args] (println opt1))
        (let [{:keys [opt2]} args] (println opt2))))
```

check the arguments if they are keyword arguments or not. As you only have one optional parameter it's easy: check if there's only one as keyword arguments require two.